# On tabChanged scrollbar scrolls to position which was in previous tab

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have `TabControl` like this

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
            Name="tabControl1" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentWorkspace, Mode=TwoWay}">
</TabControl>
```

Workspaces are `ObservableCollection` of ViewModels

DataTemplate for tabItem is

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TextViewerViewModel}">
        <ctls:TextViewerComponent/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

TextViewerComponent contains

```
<!--<ScrollViewer Name="scv" CanContentScroll="True"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1"  >-->
    <TextBox Name="logContent" IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding PageText}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1" />
    <!--</ScrollViewer>-->
```

Now problem is when I change tab scrollbar updates position to scroll position of previous tab. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

TabControl virtualize its tabs when binding is used. That means that always use same instance of control for presenting its content.

I found solution on this link [Tab virtualization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization)